# Node js mysql2 = Работа с полученным значением после завершения функции

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Не могли бы подсказать как правильно работать с полученными данными из БД

Ниже самый простой код, По идее мне нужно взять значение из таблицы БД -  закрыть соединение, и дальше что-то сделать с полученным Value. Но падаю в ошибку not defined,
Мне интересно почему, где я что упускаю?

Пробовал и mysql и mysql2/promise - результат одинаковый
После выхода из функции не могу использовать полученное из бд.

Я только учусь, больно не пинайте.

```
async function main() {
    // get the client
    const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
    
    // create the connection
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', user: 'root', password: 'root', database: 'jsnode', port: '8889'});
    
    // query database
        const [result, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `orders`');
        console.log(result);
    let resVal = result;
    console.log(resVal[0].value);
  };


 main();

console.log(resVal[0].value); // нода падает с ошибкой ***resVal is not defined***

connection.end();
```

Comment: Я сварщик не настоящий, и ноду не знаю, но во всех остальных языках принято не долбать базу запросами на подключение, и держать соединение всё время пока оно может потребоваться :) + выполнение запроса не тождественно получению ответа, ответ может быть запрошен позднее(когда вы на самом деле захотите получить доступ к данным тогда они и будут загружены с сервера, что невозможно при закрытом соединении).

Comment: Убрал закрытие в конец, все равно not defined))

Comment: По-моему, вы упускаете из вида [Области видимости](https://doka.guide/js/closures/). Переменная resVal не существует вне функции ``main()``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async function` возвращает промис. Т.ч. и работать с ней нужно как с промисом.

```
async function main() {
    // get the client
    const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
    
    // create the connection
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', user: 'root', password: 'root', database: 'jsnode', port: '8889'});
    
    // query database
        const [result, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `orders`');
        console.log(result);
    return result;
  };
(async _ => {
   const res = await main();
   console.log(res[0].value)
})()
```

Или так

```
main()
   .this(res => {
       console.log(res[0].value)
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

И, как верно заметили выше, каждый раз создавать и закрывать подключение к БД не есть хорошая практика.